# 1:1 Matching with multiple matches between treatment and control groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, matching

Hi I'm currently using a large observational dataset to estimate the average effect of a treatment. To balance the treatment and the control groups, I matched individuals based on a series of variables by using the `full_join` command.

```
matched_sample <- full_join(case, control, by = matched_varaibles)
```

The matched sample ended up with many rows because some individuals were matched more than once. I documented the number of matches found for each individual. Here I present a simpler version:

```
case_id <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F", "F")
num_controls_matched <- c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2)
control_id <- c("a" , "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a", "b", "e", "a", "b", "e", "f", "h", "a", "e", "a", "b", "e")
num_cases_matched <- c(5, 4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5) 

   case_id num_controls_matched control_id num_cases_matched
1        A                    7          a                 5
2        A                    7          b                 4
3        A                    7          c                 1
4        A                    7          d                 1
5        A                    7          e                 5
6        A                    7          f                 2
7        A                    7          g                 1
8        B                    3          a                 5
9        B                    3          b                 4
10       B                    3          e                 5
11       C                    5          a                 5
12       C                    5          b                 4
13       C                    5          e                 5
14       C                    5          f                 2
15       C                    5          h                 1
16       D                    2          a                 5
17       D                    2          e                 5
18       E                    1          a                 5
19       F                    2          b                 4
20       F                    2          e                 5
```

where case_id and control_id are IDs of those from the treatment and the control groups, num_controls_matched is the number of matches found for the treated individuals, and num_cases_matched is the number of matches found for individuals in the control group.

I would like to keep as many treated individuals in the sample as possible. I would also like to prioritise the matches for the "less popular" individuals. For example, the treated individual E was only matched to 1 control, so the match E-a should be prioritised. Then, both D and F have 2 matches. Because b has only 4 matches whilst a and e both have 5 matches, F-b should be prioritised. Therefore, D can only be matched with e. The next one should be B because it has 3 matches. However, since a, b and e have already been matched with D, E and F, B has no match (`NA`). C is matched with h because h has only 1 match. A can be matched with c, d, or g.

I would like to construct data frame to indicate the final 1:1 matches:

```
          case_id control_id
                A          g
                B         NA
                C          h
                D          e
                E          a
                F          b
```

The original dataset include more than 2,000 individuals, and some individuals have more than 30 matches. Due to the characteristic of some matching variables, propensity score matching is not what I am looking for. I will be really grateful for your help on this.

Comment: could you consider giving a bigger dataframe, ie with more rows eg 15? with at lease 6 case_id?

Comment: Thank you. It will be a bit complicated to me, but I will think about how to give a bigger data frame.

Comment: @KU99 Thanks I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <- function(df, i = 1){
  a <- df %>%
    filter(num_controls_matched == i | num_cases_matched == i)
  b <- df %>%
    filter(!(case_id %in% a$case_id | control_id %in% a$control_id))
  if (any(table(b$case_id) > 1)) fun(df, i + 1)
  else rbind(a, b)[c('case_id', 'control_id')]
}

fun(df)
  case_id control_id
1       A          a
2       B          b
3       C          c
```

Comment: Hi @KU99 thanks so much for providing this. However, I can't run this function as the command won't stop. I have to click in the Console and then press the keyboard button ESC. Would be grateful for your help on this. Thanks so much.